# How to build my own Cura GUI?

Tags: ultimaker-cura, python

I am trying to create my own Cura GUI. I am constantly getting the error:

```
UM module not found.
```

Do I need to see a UI file?

I think I am wrong.

I've installed Python, pyqt5, numpy, scipy, but I do not understand why the constant `UM module was not found`.

I know I'm doing it wrong somewhere but I can not find my mistake.

I believe there are people who will help me. There are people who know how to do it. Will you help me? What am I supposed to do?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't appear to be about tools / devices but rather general programming issue

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the entire error? As it stands the error has no context. UM probably stands for UltiMaker, (although it could be Ubuntu Mate). Are you using Uranium? Have you imported the UM module? Please provide more details, in your question. Python verison, OS version, etc.

Comment: @darthpixel - is it possible to migrate this question to SO, maybe? However, the OP _may_ be more likely to get an answer here, as there may be more chance of finding 3D printer coders here, than on SO.

Comment: Have you done basic google searches? I did a few ([1](https://www.google.co.th/search?client=opera&q=Cura+printer&sourceid=opera&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8#q=Cura+printer+um+module+was+not+found) and [2](https://www.google.co.th/search?client=opera&q=um+module+not+found&sourceid=opera&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8#q=um+module+not+found+cura)) and found some links that might help.

Comment: This question has been moved to Stack Overflow, since the actual issue is not related to 3D printing, but rather general programming.

Comment: @SamuelLiew How come this post was migrated in 2016 and only had the migration rejected today?

Comment: @Trish 3dp mod requested for it to be reverse-migrated & approved by CM

Answer (score 1):

UM could stand for UltiMaker. I think that you need to either:

- download Uranium;
- install the UM package;
- import the UM package, or;
- need to add it to your path (`PYTHONPATH`).

You may find your answer here: [help needed: ImportError: "No Module named UM" in Eclipse #510](https://github.com/Ultimaker/Cura/issues/510).

The two things that you seem to need to do are:

1. Get Uranium from https://github.com/Ultimaker/Uranium.
2. Add the path: `PYTHONPATH=/path/to/uranium/repo cura_app.py`